# sorting sql from value in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables node and sort_value. In node I have this

```
+----------------+----------------+----------+----------------+
|     nid        |     content    |   state  |      etc       |
+----------------+----------------+----------+----------------+
|      1         |     Nanuet     |    NY    |  some content  |
+----------------+----------------+----------+----------------+
|      2         |     Nanuet     |    NY    |  some content  |
+----------------+----------------+----------+----------------+
```

In sort_value table I have

```
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|  sort_order    |      city      |   state  |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|       1        |     xxxxxx     |    NY    |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|       2        |     xxxxxx     |    NY    |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
```

I want to select only nid from node table and sort selected nids based on sort_order value in sort_value table.

How can I do that??

Thanks

Comment: What is it that you're joining on? City? State? The confusing part is that you have 2 entries with the same state, what is your thought process for priority?

Comment: what is foreign key in the second table?

Comment: What is the relationship between this two tables. Without relationship you can't sort the values

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT N.nid,S.sort_order,S.city,S.state from node N INNERJOIN sort_value S WHERE N.nid=S.sort_order;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the join condition::
Try this::

```
SELECT 
*
from 
node  
INNER JOIN sort_value  ON nid=sort_order
```